# Change starting location of Explorer from Windows-E

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

How do I change which folder/location Windows Explorer opens to when I run it by pressing Windows-E?  I'd like for it to open in **My Documents** instead of at the root of **Computer**.

I've found references for [explorer.exe command line options](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853), but I don't know how to apply those options to Windows-E.

Answer (score 8):

It's a change in the Windows registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore\command
```

change the value to (example):

```
%SystemRoot%\Explorer.exe /separate,/e,C:\Program Files
```

You can use  "`%HOMEPATH%\My Documents`" for your home path ("My documents").

**Be careful when you change registry entries!**

Here are some other options for explorer.exe:

[Explorer.exe Command-Line Options for Windows XP](http://www.scribd.com/doc/43384/Command-Line-switches-for-Windows-Explorer)

```
/n                Opens a new single-pane window for the default
                  selection. This is usually the root of the drive that
                  Windows is installed on. If the window is already
                  open, a duplicate opens.

/e                Opens Windows Explorer in its default view.

/root, <object>   Opens a window view of the specified object.

/select, <object> Opens a window view with the specified folder, file,
                  or program selected.
```

Comment: I can't get this to work on Win7. Do you write the string to the Default value, i.e.: [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"
@="%SystemRoot%\\Explorer.exe /separate,/e,C:\\Program Files" I tried this, then rebooted, but no luck. Thanks for any help, Stefan!

Comment: I had the same problem and just renamed that entry to DelegateExecute.delete But I set the Default to %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /n, /e, C:\ This fixed it!